# How to work with Any in scala implicit resolution?

Tags: scala

I'm using a `Map[String, Any]` to hold many objects of different types. The work is to generate some text depending on Map's key and value, for different value types generate different results.

But when I implement this logic, it seems scala resolution every value as Any. So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: can you give some minimal example what you tried yet and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Implicit are based on types at compile time, starting from `Any` prevent it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [best way to implicitly convert Map of Any to Map of Class when extracting the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560252/best-way-to-implicitly-convert-map-of-any-to-map-of-class-when-extracting-the-va)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala doesn't have primitive types like `int`, `float`, `double`, etc. Each data type is a `class` in Scala and the `super class` of all these types is `AnyVal`, and the ultimate super class of all classes is `Any`.

You can refer to the class hierarchy [here](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fknoldus.files.wordpress.com%2F2018%2F04%2Fscala-type-system.png%3Fw%3D640&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fdzone.com%2Farticles%2Fintroduction-to-scala-type-system&docid=TSi99L0wTcIBLM&tbnid=rNY7IM8rG-pCNM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwiA0bWqhOflAhVXfX0KHTgMBBYQMwhSKAwwDA..i&w=640&h=384&bih=667&biw=1366&q=scala%20data%20type%20hierarchy&ved=0ahUKEwiA0bWqhOflAhVXfX0KHTgMBBYQMwhSKAwwDA&iact=mrc&uact=8).

Since, you want to keep the values in a Map as `Any`, Scala Map will allow you to store any type of data in the value. You need to use the parsing for the values in the type you seek. You can use `isInstanceOf` method to find out if the data has a given type and `asInstanceOf` method to get the data.

**E.g.:**

```
scala> val a = "India"
a: String = India

scala> var b = if(a.isInstanceOf[String]) a.asInstanceOf[String];
b: Any = India

scala> b.isInstanceOf[String]
res0: Boolean = true


scala> b.isInstanceOf[Integer]
res1: Boolean = false
// You can have all possible nested if-else block or a pattern-matcher to ease your job.
```

Comment: Although this is true, using asInstanceOf[_] is not the way to go. 2 things, when you have an Any as type, usually you are doing something wrong; when you don't have an else in a if statement it will return Any.

Comment: You are absolutely right on this. The type-safety is getting violated in this scenario, but this answer is solely specific to this particular question. I myself try my best to keep things type-safe. :)